# HTML/CSS Trying to add color to background with a bordered webpage

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and I came across a problem which i cant seemed to get my head around it. I have managed to put border around my webpage. I have a gradient strip image outside the border, but inside border I would like to put background color. I know, I need to put the the background color in BODY and I have done that. The background image (gradient one) works but its all over the webpage and I only want it around the border, and inside the i want a background color.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>QPI FAN CLUB</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        #bod {
            padding: 5em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="logo">
            <img class="p" src="images/logo.png" align="left">
        </div>
        <img class="d" src="images/title.gif" align="middle">
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menu2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="homepage.html"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html"><span>About Us</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="clubs.html"><span>Teams and Fixtures</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html"><span>Shop</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id=bod>
        <b><header style="color:black"></a> Manchester United </b>
        </header>

        <P>Manchester United Football Club is an English professional football club, based in Old Trafford, Greater Manchester, that plays in the Premier League. Founded as Newton Heath LYR Football Club in 1878, the club changed its name to Manchester United
            in 1902 and moved to Old Trafford in 1910.</p>


        <b><header style="color:black"></a> Manchester City </b>
        </header>
        <p>Manchester City Football Club is an English Premier League football club based in Manchester. Founded in 1880 as St. Mark's (West Gorton), they became Ardwick Association Football Club in 1887 and Manchester City in 1894. The club has played at
            the City of Manchester Stadium since 2003, having played at Maine Road from 1923. The club's most successful period was in the late 1960s and early 1970s when they won the League Championship, FA Cup, League Cup and European Cup Winners' Cup
            under the management team of Joe Mercer and Malcolm Allison.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Stylesheet:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 12%;
    background-image: url("images/mainbk.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: white;
}

#wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

img.d {
    padding-top: 3em;
    width: 450px;
}

#menu2 ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-image: url("bk2.gif");
}

#menu {
    padding-top: .5em;
}

#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    background-image: url("images/bk.gif");
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    line-height: 32px;
    line-width: 10px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -60px;
}

#logo img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Wabpage? Is that some new technology? :P

Comment: Can you add this to jsFiddle with images too so we can get a complete idea of the issue?

Comment: @bjb568 Sorry I meant Webpage.

Comment: @MattSmith can you tell me how to post my html website link here which is not live? I will do that so you will have clear idea what I am talking about.

Comment: I'd just recommend [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). You can enter your HTML and CSS and save it. You can't upload images there, you'll need to use a service like [postimage](http://postimage.org/) and then reference that in your code. This way we can all see it and fork it, too.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. For starters you should get it valid. Here's validator: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: @MattSmith Thanks alot for your Effort and I really appreciate  but i found my answer in the post below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a container div.
I edited your code like that.
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/KLaWa/

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="logo">
            <img class="p" src="images/logo.png" align="left" />
        </div>
        <img class="d" src="images/title.gif" align="middle" />
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menu2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="homepage.html"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html"><span>About Us</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="clubs.html"><span>Teams and Fixtures</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="shop.html"><span>Shop</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bod">
        <b><header style="color:black"> Manchester United 
        </header></b>

        <p>Manchester United Football Club is an English professional football club, based in Old Trafford, Greater Manchester, that plays in the Premier League. Founded as Newton Heath LYR Football Club in 1878, the club changed its name to Manchester United
            in 1902 and moved to Old Trafford in 1910.</p>


        <b><header style="color:black"> Manchester City 
        </header></b>
        <p>Manchester City Football Club is an English Premier League football club based in Manchester. Founded in 1880 as St. Mark's (West Gorton), they became Ardwick Association Football Club in 1887 and Manchester City in 1894. The club has played at
            the City of Manchester Stadium since 2003, having played at Maine Road from 1923. The club's most successful period was in the late 1960s and early 1970s when they won the League Championship, FA Cup, League Cup and European Cup Winners' Cup
            under the management team of Joe Mercer and Malcolm Allison.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#bod {
    padding: 5em;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 12%;
    background-image: url("images/mainbk.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-color: #999;
}

#wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

img.d {
    padding-top: 3em;
    width: 450px;
}

#menu2 ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-image: url("bk2.gif");
}

#menu {
    padding-top: .5em;
}

#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    background-image: url("images/bk.gif");
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 12px Arial;
    line-height: 32px;
    line-width: 10px;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -60px;
}

#logo img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Brother, it worked like charm. I didn't notice about container class which would be just for inside the border bit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, I think you need to add css rule for div with "bod" id...

So, you need to write this in your style.css file...

```
#bod {
  background-color : #ffffff; (or any other color)
}
```

to get color in the area inside the border...

You added that rule for body, and that is not correct because body represents the whole page, not just area inside the border.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it with my gradient photo and it works... Gradient is outside the border and normal color inside the border.. is that what you wanted or I misunderstood something? Check if you forgot semicolon, closing bracket or something like that...

Comment: Thank you Ryan for editing my post, I don't know why stackoverflow transformed #bod in just bod with bigger font size?? I hope this is good answer... I have seen now that I need to put code inside a tags.. sorry, I'm new here :D

Comment: thats the exact thing i want you got my point of view,i will look if i am missing any semicolon.